# WCF timeouts only when using binary serialization

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

We have a .NET 4.0 WPF client application that uses WCF to communicate to a server component (hosted in IIS). Most of the communication is done using `basicHttpBinding` and SOAP (Content-Type: text/xml); however, one endpoint in particular was switched to use a `customBinding` and binary serialization (Content-Type: application/soap+msbin1) for performance reasons.

As a result, the old url which ended in ".svc" now has an extra "/binary" extension, e.g. ".svc/binary".

This has worked fine going on 2 years now with no issues.

The other day, I received a call from a client and it appears like something is "blocking" calls that are made using this binary-enabled endpoint. What's odd is that they don't just fail outright - instead, they time out - even when I extend the timeout to something crazy like 5 minutes - the call ultimately time's out. However, as soon as I switch back to the `basicHttpBinding`, almost automatically, everything starts working great!

Could this be network security software? Client config? IIS settings? I really have no idea what could be blocking this...

Has anyone else experienced something like this??

Here is the customBinding from the client's config file:

```
<customBinding>
        <binding name="CustomBinding_IDataAccess" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
          <binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="2147483647" maxSessionSize="2147483647" maxWritePoolSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          </binaryMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport transferMode="Streamed" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" useDefaultWebProxy="true"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

Also, a quick look through the IIS logs, showed numerous entries for this endpoint:
`Request_Cancelled`, `Timer_EntityBody`, etc.

No other endpoint has messages in the log file.

Comment: Could you please activate the WCF tracing on both Client and Server? here the link in case: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx
Also provide both Client and Server WCF configurations, they should match but better to confirm.